# Mac OSX snow leopard file sharing with windows box

Tags: windows, macos, file-sharing

Having a weird issue.  I'm new to Macs and have a windows VM that I'm running on a new macbook pro via VM Fusion.  I setup a file share on the windows side (Win 7) and accessed it from the Mac side using the "Connect to Server" dialog.  I did it successfully several times, even adding in a symlink on the mac side and starting a git repository.  About halfway through my first pull from my git server the pull froze (i.e. didn't continue pulling).  I waited for quite a while like that before killing the terminal window, and after that I was no longer able to connect to the share in any fashion. I've tried removing the share on both sides, rebooting both sides, but ever since then trying to connect back to that VM gives me an error that "There was an error connecting tot he server {ip address}. Check the server name or IP Address, and then try again"

IP is right, I've tried it with the name as well (which is how I did it originally) which was also right; I can ping from the mac side to the windows side both the IP and name. I have tried editing /etc/hosts to point a name at the IP address that way, same result. I've tried turning off the windows firewall and antivirus, no difference.

I guess I'd assume it was me not doing something right on the shares, except that it went from working to not working w/o me changing any settings.  It's a new box, so it's possible that there was an OS patch (on either side) that caused the change, but I didn't notice any going in during the time in question.

UPDATE: I pulled another new mac patch down (I guess I didn't have them all) and it worked again.  Right up until I froze it again with the git issue (I had tried to resolve the pack size issue that appeared to be the root cause of the git problem, I was wrong).

Is there any process I should look at killing and restarting?  This behavior seems like there's a hung process somewhere, though shutting the mac down and booting it up again isn't helping, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Turns out that turning off sharing on the windows sid,e then turning it back on solved it.